# What is the exact difference between the game and game engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, software-design

I thought game engine are something like Unity or Unreal.
They have a editor with scene editor, some Physics library, some scripting editor and tools to improve the workflow of developer.
Furthermore, I thought game engine should independent of the actually game.(i.e.) The game engine should not have any game logic in it.

However, I watched this game engine video and I am totally confused. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK7ntA7a2vk . In the game engine video,  I don't see the game engine anywhere because it seemed as though the professor developed the game straightaway.

I hope someone can explain the exact difference between a game engine and the actual game. I also would like to know if it is worth developing a game engine or it is better to just develop the game straightaway, assuming that I am going to develop from scratch in both cases.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Appreciate it.

Comment: They both are software, one is used to develop the other.

Answer (score 2):

Game engine is a framework for building a Game. It has Tools such as map editor, animation editor, visual AI Behavior editors etc. Also it has a scripting languages like java script, C#. Examples are Unreal engine , Unity and cry engine.

But a game in other hand is a final product that was created using tools inside the Game Engine. By using a Game engine game designers can make Games without warring about the complex systems such as Rendering, AI and physics etc.

Comment: Can you give more descriptive answer!! :D

Comment: This is brief introduction. I recommend game engine architecture by jason gregory for more detail on this topic.